# Geojson data shifts when using leaflet Ajax

Tags: django, leaflet, geojson, geo

Am using django and data in my backend seems so accurate when I overlay on Leaflet openstreetmap,
when I try to load to my template the geojson data shifts.[image]

This is my django admin view.

for my template this is what I get.

[image]

need help to finalize my project

Comment: And how is that template drawn, exactly?

Comment: do you need the code

Comment: Always. Do read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .